# How to rotate an object always tangent to a circular path?

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, directx-11

I recently started to learn computer graphics and I need some help.

I'm trying to reproduce a rotation of a "stick" around a circular path in a way that the stick is always tangent to the path. I provided an image to help to illustrate the desired behaviour:

[image: Intended rotation]

I tried some approaches but never in a successful way. Below a gif with my most recent test, where the small cube represents the circular path that the stick should rotate around but being tangent to the path.

[image: Rotation achieved]

The transformations that I applied to the object world matrices:

```
XMMATRIX mScale = XMMatrixScaling(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
XMMATRIX mOrbit = XMMatrixRotationY(-t * 2.0f);
XMMATRIX mDistance = XMMatrixTranslation(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
g_World1 = mScale * mDistance * mOrbit;

XMMATRIX mScale2 = XMMatrixScaling(4.0f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
XMMATRIX mOrbit2 = mOrbit;
XMMATRIX mDistance2 = XMMatrixTranslation(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
XMMATRIX mPosition2 = XMMatrixTranslation(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
g_World2 = mScale2 * mDistance2 * mOrbit2 * mPosition2;
```

Could you help me by giving some directions/hints of what I should be looking for to solve this?

UPDATE:

Steps to reproduce this:

a) download the project [Direct3D11Tutorials](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/Direct3D11Tutorials)
b) open tutorial5
c) find the "world matrices" of the two cubes and replace them by the matrices mentioned in this post.

Thanks!

Comment: a [mre] would probably help

Comment: You can get the tangent vector by taking the vector cross product of (center to point on circle) and (vector pointing straight upwards from the plane). Then construct a transformation matrix using the vectors (tangent, up, normalize (center to point in circle)). Alternatively ,  simply rotate your stick around the Y axis by `-t * 2.0f + pi/2`.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I added some instructions on how to reproduce it.

Comment: @Botje, I tried to do as you said but I failed. It would be great if you could to show some code example. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: If you've solved your own problem you should add it as an answer rather than editing it into the question

Comment: @AlanBirtles, sorry! I did it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the behaviour I wanted by translating the Z coordinate of the stick instead of the X:

```
//small cube as reference
XMMATRIX mScale = XMMatrixScaling(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);    
g_World1 = mScale;

//stick rotating around the small cube
XMMATRIX mScale2 = XMMatrixScaling(3.0f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
XMMATRIX mOrbit2 = XMMatrixRotationY(-t * 2.0f);
XMMATRIX mDistance2 = XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
g_World2 = mScale2 * mDistance2 * mOrbit2;
```

Result:

[image: Result]

In case someone has another fancier way of doing this, please let me know.